# Change the text without re-execution in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, 3d

How can I change a text in Tkinter without closing and running again?
Please help me

How can I change a text in Tkinter without closing and running again?

Please help me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.